# Amplitudes for state of a photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}
\newcommand{\bke}[3]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \middle| #3 \right>}$
In [this lecture video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCwUKsWt8z4&list=PLB3CF07ACB3DBC849&index=3)(jump to 10:15) of Prof. Binney, he is discussing passing photons through a polariod. At 10:50, he writes down the state of the incoming photon $\ket{\psi}$ as $$\ket{\psi} = \cos{\theta}\ket{\rightarrow} + \sin{\theta}\ket{\uparrow}.$$

[image: diagram]

$\ket{\uparrow}$ represents the state when the photon is always blocked and $\ket{\rightarrow}$ represents the state when the photon always passes.

How can one write the amplitudes of $\ket{\rightarrow}$ and $\ket{\uparrow}$ as $\cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{\theta}$ respectively? I understand the classical explanation of taking the components of the electric field but how can we obtain those amplitudes quantum mechanically?

Ref: Binney, James; Skinner, David *The Physics of Quantum Mechanics*, Oxford University Press, 2014, pp. 20-22. [Google books link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8d51AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}
\newcommand{\bke}[3]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \middle| #3 \right>}$

It comes from the normalisation condition. A general state is given by:
$$\ket{\psi} = a\ket{\rightarrow} + b\ket{\uparrow}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{where }|a|^2+|b|^2=1$$
Then we can parametrise it in terms of just one variable $\theta$ that then gives: $$\ket{\psi} = \cos{\theta}\ket{\rightarrow} + \sin{\theta}\ket{\uparrow}$$

Comment: Yes, how can we state that the parameter $\theta$ is equal to the one shown in the diagram?

Comment: Also, parametrisation does not tell me why $a = \cos{\theta}$ and not $\sin{\theta}$.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The parametrisation variable is somehow related to the $\theta$ in the diagram. It turns out in this case that the parametrisation variable equals to $\theta$. I can take $b = \cos{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is the parametrisation variable and say that $\phi = 90^\circ - \theta$.

Comment: The expectation of either of the state gives you the coefficients. So classically over lots of measurements, you'll get the image shown.